# Extend currenty script if radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use the following script, to display a block if a radio button is checked. I want to extent this code, by adding a class to another ID. But for some reason the addition does not work. The class is not added or removed. What am I missing?

Default code, works perfect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
```

NEW code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('billing:postcode_input:output').classList.add('business');
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('billing:postcode_input:output').classList.remove('business');
}

</script>
```

Comment: did you tried with .addClass() ?

Comment: why else block doesnt have paranthesis?

Comment: Try to check `document.getElementById('billing:postcode_input:output')` in console as when i tried to access in the above manner then it didn't work.
Hence I guess the issue is in id of the element.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is "billing:postcode_input:output" an valid ID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('YOURID').classList.add('business');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('YOURID').classList.remove('business');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to inform you @PraveenKumar then I think the reason why you are getting downvotes for an answer that is, in fact, correct, is because it could easily be answered in the comment section of the question or marked as a type error mistake.